# Send Webm buffer to php server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, webrtc

I'm recording video and audio from the browser using MediaRecorder. After I finish recording I try to upload it to the server with something like this:

```
function upload() {
  var fileName = 'video.webm';
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('filename', fileName);
  formData.append('blob', blobs);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/upload.php',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
  });

  xhr('upload.php', formData, function (fName) {
    window.open(location.href + fName);
  });

  function xhr(url, data, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
          alert('Done');
        }
    };
    request.open('POST', url);
    request.send(data);
  }
}
```

Apparently the $_FILES variable doesn't get set in php, but the $_POST does. The file name has been passed correctly, but if I output the blobs to a file, I'm not able to reproduce the file in an html5 video object, so I guess something is wrong with that.
Could anyone explain what's the best way to accomplish this upload?

Thanks